# Loading texture SFML causes program to crash

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I'm trying to load an sf::Texture, but every time I run the program, my computer starts beeping (no joke), and the command prompt outputs a bunch of characters that look like ancient Egyptian hieroglyphics.
Relevant code:

```
#pragma once

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

class TextureLoader {
public:
    sf::Texture runway;

    ~TextureLoader(){}

    TextureLoader() {
        runway.loadFromFile("Runway.png");
    }
};
```

Runway.png does exist, because I've tested creating an ifstream and it loads the image fine.

The debugger complains of an "Access violation reading location", but the location changes each time and I've never been able to find the memory space it points to in the debugger.  Every object appears to be fine except for the texture.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing debug/release version of SFML libraries with your program's debug/release version. If your program is debug, use debug libraries of SFML, if your program is in release version, use release version of SFML.

Comment: Care to clarify? What can I do to fix it.  I tried removing the dll's that were for release, but now I get an error that it can't find the dll's

Comment: @Tips48 What's your IDE and exact version of it?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2013, and SFML 2.1

Comment: Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and
Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories, you need to do it both for release and debug versions of your project for debug/release versions of SFML lib

Answer (score 0):

People who are still figuring out how to set the project settings, please do as follows (note the "-d" for debug):

[image: Debug settings]

[image: Release settings]
[image: x86 for x32]